# Get next alarm value in Samsung mobile

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

```
Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

The above code returns next system alarm value in HTC and Sony Ericsson android phones.
But in case of Samsung mobiles, it is not returning next alarm value. Can anyone give me alternate code or change in above code that gives me next alarm value in a Samsung device?

**Edited:** I have digged out that, Samsung device gives us out put in hh:mm aa format (e.g. 06:45 AM).
Where as HTC and Sony Ericsson android device gives us out put in EEE hh:mm aa format (e.g. WED 06:45 AM).
Here in Samsung device we can not identify that alarm is set for which date. Now my next challange is to find out the way which give me weekday too.

Thanks.

Comment: Hassan, thanks for grammar change suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above codes on Samsung device. It gives me EEE hh:mm aa format (e.g. WED 06:45 AM).

So can you be more specific which Samsung device? I tried using Samsung Galaxy Nexus with no problem.

Comment: I am trying on Samsung Galaxy Mini(Android 2.2.3; Model number GT-S5570) and Samsung Galaxy FIT.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have those devices. I hope someone else could share their finding here. I expect this technique will give us "standard" values throughout variety of devices.

Comment: You are executing on which Android Version?